# Deleting Git repository in Eclipse has deleted my project

Tags: java, eclipse, git

Deleting Git repo in eclipse has deleted my project in the workspace. I want to know why it has happened. I saw similar questions but still not the same as this case.
**I'm new to GitHub repository.**

Notes: I just replicated the error with an example project "Abc".
[image: 1]

**Step1:** I've connected or shared my old project(Abc) with Git by creating a local repo(repository_abc) for this old project. (Abc > Menu Options -> Team -> Share -> create Git repo wizard)
[image]

then repo view

[image]

**Step2:** And then I decided to make some changes to my project before moving to Git, so I've disconnected my old project from git.
(Abc > Menu Options -> Team -> Disconnect)
[image]
now the repo view

[image]

**Step3:** Deleted the same repository(repository_abc) from Git explorer as I don't want to see it there (repository_abc >  Menu Options -> delete rep.. -> selected first 2 options out of 3 in the list)
[image]
Next,

[image]

**Then I realized it has deleted my old project(Abc) from the workspace.**
I tried to restore from Local History but unluckily nothing has saved in Eclipse Local History.

Anyways I've backed up the project 2 weeks back.

Comment: In your last screenshot, the first checkbox is to delete the Git repository (history, branches, tags, etc.) and with the second checkbox also the current checked-out files will be deleted.

Comment: You keep saying "old project"...but I dont see any new project. You are working on one project (Abc) and one repo (repository_abc). Of course based on your selections in last screenshot...when you delete...it will delete Abc project as well.